# How to impute missing value in time series data with mean value of the same day and time in python

Tags: python, time-series, interpolation, imputation

I have multivariate time series data with missing values. Is there any way I can impute the missing value with mean value of the same day of week and time? For example, value for account 1 on 2019-2-1 (Friday) at 2am shall be filled with mean value for account 1 on every Friday at 2am.

```
account              1     2     3
2019-2-1 01:00:00    15    12    10
2019-2-1 02:00:00    Nan   11    9
2019-2-1 03:00:00    10    11    3
...
2019-31-1 22:00:00   11    Nan   4
2019-31-1 23:00:00   Nan   12    4
2019-31-1 24:00:00   10    10    Nan
```

I have tried `interpolate` using polynomial but this method is irrelevant in my case. Maybe `groupby` can help but not sure how to utilize it when working with time-series index.

Comment: Are you concerned at all about potentially using values from the future for imputation?

Comment: no i am not restricted to that. value from future can be included as well

Answer (score 1):

If you are not concerned about using future values for imputation, you can use this for each column:

Sample pandas dataframe (with 'date_time' index of dtype='datetime64[ns]'):

```
                    acct_1  acct_2  acct_3
date_time           
2019-02-07 01:00:00   15.0    12.0    10.0
2019-02-07 02:00:00    NaN    11.0     9.0
2019-02-07 03:00:00   10.0    11.0     3.0
2019-01-31 22:00:00   11.0     NaN     4.0
2019-01-31 02:00:00    NaN    12.0     4.0
2019-01-24 02:00:00   10.0    10.0     NaN
```

Code and result:

```
df['acct_1'] = (df
    .groupby((df.index.dayofweek * 24) + (df.index.hour))
    .transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean())
)
df
                    acct_1  acct_2  acct_3
date_time           
2019-02-07 01:00:00   15.0    12.0    10.0
2019-02-07 02:00:00   10.0    11.0     9.0
2019-02-07 03:00:00   10.0    11.0     3.0
2019-01-31 22:00:00   11.0     NaN     4.0
2019-01-31 02:00:00   10.0    12.0     4.0
2019-01-24 02:00:00   10.0    10.0     NaN
```

Comment: Thank you very much @AlexK for the ideas. Is there any way to do it more efficiently since I have thousands of accounts? I have tried 'df=(df.groupby('(df.index.dayofweek* 24) + (df.index.hour)).transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()), axis=1))' but got error Transform function invalid for data types

Comment: @m_ana I think if you just remove the `axis=1` argument from your code, that should solve the problem and will apply the transformation to every column.  That works on this toy dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `groupby`, `interpolate` or `rolling` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.DataFrame({"account": pd.date_range(start="2019-02-01", periods=1000, freq="H"), "1": range(1000), "2": range(1000,2000), "3": range(1000,0,-1)})
    df.loc[2:3, "1"] = np.nan
    df.loc[6, "2"] = np.nan
    df.loc[7, "3"] = np.nan
    df["day"] = df["account"].dt.date
    print(df)
#     df_result = df.groupby("day").apply(lambda day: day.interpolate(method="linear"))
    df_groupby = df.groupby("day")
    df["1"] = df_groupby["1"].transform(lambda col: col.rolling(2, min_periods=1).mean())
    print(df)
```

Results:

```
                account      1       2       3         day
0   2019-02-01 00:00:00    0.0  1000.0  1000.0  2019-02-01
1   2019-02-01 01:00:00    1.0  1001.0   999.0  2019-02-01
2   2019-02-01 02:00:00    NaN  1002.0   998.0  2019-02-01
3   2019-02-01 03:00:00    NaN  1003.0   997.0  2019-02-01
4   2019-02-01 04:00:00    4.0  1004.0   996.0  2019-02-01
..                  ...    ...     ...     ...         ...
995 2019-03-14 11:00:00  995.0  1995.0     5.0  2019-03-14
996 2019-03-14 12:00:00  996.0  1996.0     4.0  2019-03-14
997 2019-03-14 13:00:00  997.0  1997.0     3.0  2019-03-14
998 2019-03-14 14:00:00  998.0  1998.0     2.0  2019-03-14
999 2019-03-14 15:00:00  999.0  1999.0     1.0  2019-03-14

[1000 rows x 5 columns]
                account      1       2       3         day
0   2019-02-01 00:00:00    0.0  1000.0  1000.0  2019-02-01
1   2019-02-01 01:00:00    0.5  1001.0   999.0  2019-02-01
2   2019-02-01 02:00:00    1.0  1002.0   998.0  2019-02-01
3   2019-02-01 03:00:00    NaN  1003.0   997.0  2019-02-01
4   2019-02-01 04:00:00    4.0  1004.0   996.0  2019-02-01
..                  ...    ...     ...     ...         ...
995 2019-03-14 11:00:00  994.5  1995.0     5.0  2019-03-14
996 2019-03-14 12:00:00  995.5  1996.0     4.0  2019-03-14
997 2019-03-14 13:00:00  996.5  1997.0     3.0  2019-03-14
998 2019-03-14 14:00:00  997.5  1998.0     2.0  2019-03-14
999 2019-03-14 15:00:00  998.5  1999.0     1.0  2019-03-14

[1000 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: I think OP wants time to be accounted for, not just date.  And your answer still leaves `NaN`s and transform with rolling changes every value in the column, not just `NaN`s.

Comment: Yes. I left `NaN` values for OP to adjust parameters according to his or her needs. He or she can apply `interpolate linear` method, which is commented in my code and will remove all the `NaN` values, or change parameter of `rolling` method, or apply above method several times to remove `NaN`s.

Answer (score 0):

use group by to get the average by day of the week and hour then map the average where the value is nan using the dow and hour as a key

```
 data=[
 ('2019-02-07 01:00:00',  15,    12,    10),
 ('2019-02-07 02:00:00',    np.nan,   11,    9),
 ('2019-02-07 03:00:00',    10,    11,    3),
 ('2019-01-31 22:00:00',   11,    np.nan,   4),
 ('2019-01-31 02:00:00',   np.nan,    12,    4),
 ('2019-01-24 02:00:00',   10,    10,    float('nan'))]

 df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['date','acct1','acct2','acct3'])
 df['date']=df['date'].apply(lambda row: datetime2.strptime(str(row),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
 df['dow']=df['date'].apply(lambda row: row.dayofweek)
 df['hour']=df['date'].apply(lambda row: row.hour)
 df.set_index('date')

 grouped_acct1=df.groupby(['dow','hour'])['acct1'].mean()
 grouped_acct2=df.groupby(['dow','hour'])['acct2'].mean()
 grouped_acct3=df.groupby(['dow','hour'])['acct3'].mean()

 for key,item in df.iterrows():
     df.loc[key,'acct1_mean']= grouped_acct1[(grouped_acct1.index.get_level_values(0)==item.dow) & (grouped_acct1.index.get_level_values(1)==item.hour)].values
     df.loc[key,'acct2_mean']= grouped_acct2[(grouped_acct2.index.get_level_values(0)==item.dow) & (grouped_acct2.index.get_level_values(1)==item.hour)].values
     df.loc[key,'acct3_mean']= grouped_acct3[(grouped_acct3.index.get_level_values(0)==item.dow) & (grouped_acct3.index.get_level_values(1)==item.hour)].values


 for key,item in df.iterrows():
      if math.isnan(item['acct1']):
          df.loc[key,'acct1']=item['acct1_mean'] 
      else: 
          df.loc[key,'acct1']=item['acct1']   

     if math.isnan(item['acct2']):
         df.loc[key,'acct2']=item['acct2_mean'] 
     else: 
         df.loc[key,'acct2']=item['acct2']   

     if math.isnan(item['acct3']):
         df.loc[key,'acct3']=item['acct3_mean'] 
     else: 
         df.loc[key,'acct3']=item['acct3']   

  print(df)
```

output

```
  date                  acct1  acct2  acct3  dow  hour  acct1_mean  acct2_mean  \
0 2019-02-07 01:00:00   15.0   12.0   10.0    3     1        15.0        12.0   
1 2019-02-07 02:00:00   10.0   11.0    9.0    3     2        10.0        11.0   
2 2019-02-07 03:00:00   10.0   11.0    3.0    3     3        10.0        11.0   
3 2019-01-31 22:00:00   11.0    NaN    4.0    3    22        11.0         NaN   
4 2019-01-31 02:00:00   10.0   12.0    4.0    3     2        10.0        11.0   
5 2019-01-24 02:00:00   10.0   10.0    6.5    3     2        10.0        11.0    

   acct3_mean  
0        10.0  
1         6.5  
2         3.0  
3         4.0  
4         6.5  
5         6.5
```

​